# After retrieving data from database, and showing them in a table, long lines extend the cell, instead of breaking

Tags: css, jsp, xslt

I'm using the following xslt code snippet to show text in a cell:

```
<td>
    <pre style="font-family: verdana,helvetica,sans-serif; white-space: pre-wrap;">
         <xsl:value-of select="Field[@ColumnName='DESCRIPTION']"/>
    </pre>
</td>
```

The table has a fix `600px` size, but multiple JSP pages uses that, and I only have access to edit the `< td>` (maybe the `< tr>` tags. What would be the proper css style to force the lines to break?

The `white-space: pre-wrap;` css is not working here, because it's responsible to preserve formatting coming from an input field, and it works just fine. But if the data is inserted with sql (without using the input field (so it has no formatting, line breaks for example, just a single line), then it doesn't break.

And I'm looking for an IE friendly solution!

EDIT:

I've tried all the following css styles, and nothing works:

```
<td style="word-wrap: break-word; text-wrap: normal; white-space: pre;">
    <pre style="font-family: verdana,helvetica,sans-serif;">
       <xsl:value-of select="Field[@ColumnName='DESCRIPTION']"/>
    </pre>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code after the `EDIT`, you've moved your wrapping CSS to the parent `<td>`.

The HTML `<pre>` element has its own wrapping rules, which supersede the wrapping style of any ancestor element.  Add `white-space: pre-wrap;` to the inline CSS on the `<pre>` element and you should get the display you're looking for.

(Tested provisionally in Chrome 58 and IE 11.)